# How to set initial time in Cypress and allow time to flow?

Tags: cypress

I want to start Cypress with consistent time, e.g. first Monday of July of current year. I can use `clock` to override current time:

```js
cy.clock(new Date(2023, 7, 1, 12, 0, 0), ['Date']);
```

but then I'd have to use `cy.tick` whenever I want to simulate some time passing. Is there a way to set the initial time for tests but allow the time to flow on its own? So that 5 seconds after calling `cy.clock` it is "2023-07-01 12:00:05", not permanently "2023-07-01 12:00:00".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be easy, not sure why it isn't.

Here is a custom command and a proof-of-concept test to confirm it.

**/cypress/support/commands.js**

```js
const FakeTimers = require("@sinonjs/fake-timers");

Cypress.Commands.add("setAppDate", (targetDate) => {
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    const clock = FakeTimers.withGlobal(win).install({
      now: targetDate,
      toFake: ["Date"],
      shouldAdvanceTime: true,
      advanceTimeDelta: 40,
    });
  });
})
```

**Test**

```js
it('demo custom command for cy.clock "shouldAdvanceTime" option', () => {
  
  const targetDate = new Date(2027, 7, 1, 12, 0, 0)

  cy.window()
    .should((win) => {
      const dateBefore = new win.Date()
      expect(dateBefore).be.lt(targetDate) // app has date before targetDate
    })

  cy.setAppDate(targetDate)

  // doesn't work in this test
  // cy.clock(targetDate, ['Date'], { shouldAdvanceTime: true, })

  cy.window()
    .should(win => {
      const dateAfter = new win.Date()
      expect(dateAfter).to.deep.eq(targetDate) // date changed to targetDate
    })
  
  cy.wait(1000)                                // let some time go by

  cy.window()
    .should(win => {
      const afterWait = new win.Date()
      expect(afterWait).to.be.gt(targetDate)   // date has incremented
    })
})
```

**Results**

[image]

---

#### Background

Looking at the source for [cy.clock()](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/src/cypress/clock.ts), can see it is wrapping `@sinonjs/fake-timers`

```js
import _ from 'lodash'
import fakeTimers from '@sinonjs/fake-timers'

const install = (win, now, methods) => {
  return fakeTimers.withGlobal(win).install({
    now,
    toFake: methods,
  })
}
```

[@sinonjs/fake-timers](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers#api-reference) has an option called `shouldAdvanceTime`

> **var clock = FakeTimers.install([config])**
>
> | Parameter | Type | Default | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | config.shouldAdvanceTime | Boolean | false | tells FakeTimers to increment mocked time automatically based on the real system time shift (e.g. the mocked time will be incremented by 20ms for every 20ms change in the real system time) |

Unfortunately, `cy.clock()` does not expose that option, but you can use it directly in your specs via the custom command above.

Comment: This works, thank you so much! For future reference: the call to `setAppDate` should be placed after `cy.visit`, otherwise the window object will change and it'll seem like it doesn't work. Or, to apply it everywhere, the call can be placed in a listener to the `window:before:load` event.

Comment: Apparently this works, but it is not documented: cy.clock(time, ['Date'], {
      shouldAdvanceTime: true,
    })

Comment: Would be nice, but it didn't work in my test.

Comment: I clarified the test above.

Comment: I found the `onBeforeLoad` event on `cy.visit` useful here to ensure it applies the new date early enough